# Using Ajax with Rails link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using link_to tag to change the validity:

```
  <%= link_to "Mark as " + (doc.is_valid ? "invalid" : "valid"), 
                  :action =>'change_validity',:id => doc.id %>
```

Here, is_valid is a field in a table with boolean value. When it is true link will show
as "Mark as invalid". When I click the link it will call the method "change_validity" method
in controller. The method will toggle the is_valid field and show "Mark as valid" in view.

This one I want to do using AJAX. I tried to using link_to_remote. But I couldn't get it.
Can anyone explain how to do it???

Answer (score 1):

Make one partial page.
_preview.html.erb and put below code into your partial view

```
<%= link_to_remote "Mark as " + (doc.is_valid ? "invalid" : "valid"), :update => "update", :url => { :action => "change_validity", :id => doc.id } %>
```

In your main view file.put below code

```
<div id="update">
    <%= render :partial => "preview", :locals => { :doc => @doc} %>
</div>
```

In your controller should have below code

```
def change_validity
// do stuff here
render :partial => "preview", :locals => { :doc => @doc}, :content_type => 'text/html'
end
```

Comment: second update is id of div. when you click first time, it does ajax call to your controller action, there you write a code to change valid into your db, then render partial view with latest update into db that html then display into div

Comment: it is not working.. I think ajax call is not happening.. when I click on link nothing is happening. I added logger line in controller it is not coming in log file.

Comment: if you have firefox browser, then install firebug addon and in this addon you can see all ajax requests with data

Comment: Browser console is throwing error called => ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined

Comment: can you paste what are js files included into your page ? it seems ajax related js files not rendering on your page.

Answer (score 0):

link_to_remote is not available in Rails 3. Add **:remote => true** to your link.

```
link_to "Mark as " + (doc.is_valid ? "invalid" : "valid"), 
              change_validity_path(:id => doc.id), :remote => true
```

EDIT: for rails < 3 try

```
link_to_remote(
        "Mark as " + (doc.is_valid ? "invalid" : "valid"),
        :url => {:action => "change_validity", :id => doc.id},
        :update => "your_div_id",
        :html => {:class => "something"}
      )
```

Comment: change_validity is method in my controller not a model.

Comment: could you explain what should be the update and html fields ??

Comment: :update needs the e.g. id of your <div> where the response html code should go. Or you can do it on the controller side using "render :update do |page| ... end" block.